# Problems with wifi with Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have intsalled Ubuntu Touch (15.04 r2) on a Nexus 4.
Everything is working fine, except the wi-fi.
It is enabled, succesfully connected to the home wi-fi network, but it does't work properly. I was able to surf the web just few times, it is very slow, and many time the browser stops for time out.
The wi-fi net works properly with other devices.
any idea? I forgot some steps?
thanks
Marco

Comment: I experience something similar - The wifi seems connected (and the device is visible from the router) but it doesn't transfer data. So far I've needed 3G to connect in wifi areas.

Comment: I have the same problem using Ubuntu Touch 15.04 OTA-8.5 and OTA-9 on a MX 4 and a Linksys 1900 AC. It did work just fine with earlier releases. I have changed the Linksys to act as an bridge instead of using it as an access point in the same time as problem started. When browsing it stops and gets timed out after a minute or two. The same for streaming radio or video. After reconnection or change of wifi-network (5KHz/2.4KHz) it runs again for a minute or two.

But I have bad experience with arbitary wifi networks too. 

Mobile Networks works fine.